# searching for last group of text between specific characters

Tags: python-3.x, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a text file that has data printed in the following way

```
---
1A
1B
1C
---
---
2A
2B
2C
---
---
3A
3B
3C
.
.
3n
---
NA
.
.
Nn
---
```

essentially lines of text encased around lines of --- to ---.

I am looking to extract the contents between the last occurrence of --- to ---, so far using regex I have have managed to narrow it down to `(?<=---)(.*?)(?=---)` however this finds all occurrences and I would only like the last.

Comment: You can try `.*(?<=---)(.*?)(?=---)` to get only last match [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/MET0BY/1)

Comment: Ahh many thanks! i have been scratching my head over this for a while, thank you!

Comment: Note that @Andrej set the single-line mode flag (s) so that .* will match newlines. Nice answer, Andrej.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you match the string with the regular expression

```
r'(?s).*^---\r?\n(.*)(?=^---)'
```

capture group 1 will contain the string of interest.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Thdgyb/2/)

Python's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(?s)        set single-line mode so that '.' matches newlines
.*          match 0+ characters (greedily)
^---\r?\n   match line '---'
(.*)        match 0+ characters in capture group 1
(?=^---)    match '---' at beginning of line in positive lookahead
```

The first `.*`, being greedy, gobbles up characters, including newlines and hyphens, until it has consumed the line `'---'` that is followed later in the string by one more line `'---'`. It cannot go beyond the penultimate line `'---'` because it it were to do so it would have to consume the last `'---'` line, yet the match must be followed by the last `'---'` line.